# How to select a record if the query returns one row, or select no record if the query returns more rows?

Tags: sql, oracle

I require to select a row if there is only one row exists, if there are more rows, it should select 0 rows.

Comment: How do you select a row? Do you write a program that selects smth from some table? What returns 0 records? Do you mean some function returns 0? Are you using PL/SQL or SQL only? This is why you have messy answers...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using PL/SQL, then selecting the column using `select-into` will throw a `too_many_rows` exception if there's more than one row returned:

```
declare
  var table.column%type;
begin
  select column
  into   var
  from   table
  where  ...;
end;
```

If you want to do this just using SQL, then you can do something like:

```
select *
from
  (select s.*, count(*) over () c
   from
    (select *
     from table
     where ...
     and   rownum <= 2
    ) s
)
where c = 1
```

**UPDATE**

As DazzaL says in the comments, the reason for the `rownum <= 2` restriction is to short-circuit the query if there's more than 2 rows in the result set. This can give significant performance benefits if the dataset is large.

Comment: I found what i was looking, thanks. But here, it will work without `rownum <= 2` subquery.

Comment: Using `over() clause` below sql could work.
`SELECT * FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) over() cnt ,fld1, fld2 FROM tbl1)
WHERE  cnt = 1`

Comment: @StalinGino the reason Chris put `rownum <= 2` is for performance. i.e. only count two rows max (otherwise if you're query matched millions of rows, you'd be asking Oracle to count them all and then discard them all if you had 2+ rows which would take more time).

Answer (score 3):

I came up with this, just for the heck of it, using a CTE

```
With counter as
( select count(any_field) as cnt from your_query
)
SELECT
  your_query
WHERE exists (SELECT cnt from Counter WHERE cnt=1)
```

1 row when there's 1 record - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/84c7b/2
0 rows when more than 1 rec - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/95c4a/1

**EDIT**
or if you want to avoid repeating the whole query... an example :
*(using the schema from sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6a2d8/117 )*

```
With results as
( select * from montly_sales_totals
),
counter as
( SELECT count(name) as cnt FROM results
)
SELECT *
FROM results
WHERE exists (SELECT cnt from Counter WHERE cnt=5)
```

Comment: I could say the same, `select * from table where x=y and (select count(*) from table where x=y) = 1` is better :)

Comment: ok, edited to show how to avoid repeating the whole query. I do like a CTE :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT fld1, fld2
FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) over() cnt ,fld1, fld2 FROM tbl WHERE fld1 = 'key')
WHERE cnt = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

> I require to select a row if there is only one row exists, if there
>   are more rows, it should select 0 rows.

I assume the table contains only the row(s) you are interested to see (or not to see), in that case I would write something like

```
select *
  from table1
 where 1 = (select count(1) 
              from table1
           )
```

In case you want to see only one row from a subset of results from your table, I would go for something like:

```
with t as ( select *
              from table1
             where [put here your condition]
)
select *
  from t
 where 1 = (select count(1) 
              from t
           )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT f1,f2
FROM  Table
WHERE (f1 = @f1) AND (f2=@f2) AND (f3=@f3)
GROUP BY f1,f2
HAVING (COUNT(*) = 1)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM
(SELECT count(id) as 'cnt', col1, col2 FROM table_name WHERE col1='value') 
WHERE cnt=1;
```

Comment: I think that the asterix does'nt let you mix it with any other column/function.

*Select *, count(id)* would'nt work

Comment: count() is an aggregate function, it wont allow us to add * or other column unless specified in group by expression. this will not work. When using `count(*) over()` which is said in another answer, it will work

Answer (score -1):

DECLARE COL_COUNT NUMBER;
BEGIN
COL_COUNT: = 0 ;
SELECT COUNT (1) INTO COL_COUNT FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '(ur table name)';
IF COL_COUNT = 0 THEN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  ('select * from dual') ;
END IF;
END;

Comment: Im not looking for pl sql code. In simple way i can use count function as `select * from table where x=y and (select count(*) from table where x=y) = 1`, there is no need for plsql for this